# 'AssertionError: Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled'

Tags: python

I use my macbook to run this '`python3 demo.py --indir ${img_directory} --outdir examples/res`' command to get the human pose, but the error says 'Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled'.

I have tried to reinstall the 'torch' package which version is '`torch-1.0.0-cp37-none-macosx_10_7_x86_64.whl`' ,but it dose not work.

```
guozirongMBP:AlphaPose guozirong$ python3 demo.py --list examples/list-coco-demo.txt --indir /Users/guozirong/Downloads/image  --outdir examples/res --save_img
Loading YOLO model..
Process Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 297, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 99, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/guozirong/AlphaPose/dataloader.py", line 151, in getitem_yolo
    img_k, orig_img_k, im_dim_list_k = prep_image(im_name_k, inp_dim)
  File "/Users/guozirong/AlphaPose/yolo/preprocess.py", line 42, in prep_image
    dim = orig_im.shape[1], orig_im.shape[0]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo.py", line 50, in <module>
    det_loader = DetectionLoader(data_loader, batchSize=args.detbatch).start()
  File "/Users/guozirong/AlphaPose/dataloader.py", line 282, in __init__
    self.det_model.cuda()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 260, in cuda
    return self._apply(lambda t: t.cuda(device))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 187, in _apply
    module._apply(fn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 187, in _apply
    module._apply(fn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 187, in _apply
    module._apply(fn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 193, in _apply
    param.data = fn(param.data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 260, in <lambda>
    return self._apply(lambda t: t.cuda(device))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py", line 161, in _lazy_init
    _check_driver()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py", line 75, in _check_driver
    raise AssertionError("Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled")
AssertionError: Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AssertionError: Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54014220/assertionerror-torch-not-compiled-with-cuda-enabled)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got this error while running the notebook on google colab and then I realised I didn't changed the network settings to use accelerator "GPU". So its very important to check whether your system supports Nvidia CUDA Capable GPU or not.